# $g(n)\in\omega(n^r)$ but $g(f(n))\in o(n^{r-1})$

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(n)\in o(n)$. Is it always possible to find a function $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a constant $r>1$  such that $g(n)\in\omega(n^r)$ but $g(f(n))\in o(n^{r-1})$?

(See the definitions of $o$ and $\omega$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(n)= n/\log n\in o(n)$, $g(n)\in \omega (n^r)$ implies $|g(n)|
\geq Mn^r$ but $|g(f(n))| \geq M n^r/\log^rn\notin o(n^{r-1})$.